# Embeding notebook to readme.md file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a notebook say abc.ipynb. I want to publish it on my doc page i.e. readme.md. During the git pipeline readme.md should run abc.ipynb and store results in readme.md.

For example-

abc.ipynb

```
Cell 1:
     a = 1
     b = 2 
     sum = a + b
     sum
```

readme.md

```
     a = 1
     b = 2 
     sum = a + b
     sum
3
```

Is there a way to do that.